# SciChart changing the color map on a FastHeatMapRenderableSeries

Tags: wpf, scichart

I'm a long-time user of SciChart, but it's an old version (3.1). I've just started using `FastHeatMapRenderableSeries` for the first time, and there is a requirement for a user to alter the chart's gradient stops. I've implemented a UI to do this (see image), which involves dragging markers that updates their respective gradient stop within the ColorMap's LinearGradientBrush. It's working in as much as gradient changes can be seen in the chart's `HeatColorMap` (not shown on this screenshot), and also in my "drag" control (a Rectangle whose Fill is bound to the ColorMap's brush).

The problem is that the colours within the chart itself don't change - perhaps I was being a little too hopeful that this would happen automatically! Is this possible, or will I have to recreate the series each time there has been a change to the gradient?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually have this working in a later version of SciChart. Im not sure which version exactly but it was introduced at some point. Have a look at this forum post which discusses [a bug in the heatmap color map binding in v5](https://www.scichart.com/questions/wpf/how-to-dynamically-adjust-the-range-of-the-heatmap).

In the v6 examples suite, you can drag the heat map legend and recolour the chart automatically, so we know in principle this works.

Very cool image by the way!

Comment: Many thanks. I've been singing the praises of SciChart for 7+ years, and this might be the excuse to finally upgrade to the latest version! I'm assuming I should expect a number of breaking changes if I was to do so? I use SciChart heavily throughout our software. Also, does v6 still support .Net Framework (4.6)? We haven't made the jump to Core yet.

Comment: It still supports .net 4.5.2 and up yes. I think there was a change from FastHeatmapRenderableSeries which was made obsolete and FastUniformHeatmapRenderableSeries / FastNonUniformHeatmapRenderableSeries in its place. These are higher performance too. Give it a try? If it works out of the box it might be a good thing for you. https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/The%20Heatmap%20Type.html

Comment: I was thinking more in general terms of breaking changes across the library. It's our first time using the heatmap, but there are dozens of other charts being used across our application, at times with quite complex customisations, modifiers, annotations, etc. Just concerned about getting bogged down fixing issues and retesting if there are likely to be extensive changes jumping from v3 to v6.